# Navigator/MaterialPageRoute Missing Arguments Error

Tags: dynamic, flutter, navigator, materialpageroute

I have a BUTTON ,here is some code:
[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/meoic.png)

and i got the error like this:[image]

I've never met an error like this, but when i add the 'dynamic' like this:
[image]

Comment: Please ask your question in the title instead of stating you have a question. Also consider putting the code and errors inside code blocks and quotes or at least an image instead of a URL to an image. Also you never really asked a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change your Code and implement this :

```
onPressed: () {
  Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Newfa()),
  );
}
```